# Auto SMS does not work after long inactivity of app

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcast, receiver

Here i have made app which listen to every SMS receives and then send SMS as per the condition define. This app perfectly work without problem for limited time. But after long inactivity of app (i.e 12 hr), it does not send any SMS for any SMS recevies. During this inactivity, user is using his mobile to make call but does not do anything with the app. If i see the app info status, it shows that app is running. Since it works fine at the beginning but later only does not response hence it look like code does not have any problem. please help me to understand this problem. Any expert suggestion highly welcome.

```
    public class IncommingSMS2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String phoneNumber;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

     public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                 Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + phoneNumber + "; message: " );

                    if (Objects.equals(message, "Where")) {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                              smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "test", null, null);

                    }

                } // bundle is null
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    }
    }
```

here i have manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permiss‌​ion>                                                     
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission‌​>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 
    <receiver android:name=".IncommingSMS2">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: set high priority in manifest file

Comment: How did you declare it in the manifest?

Comment: Dear Jordy, here i have manifest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> <receiver android:name=".IncommingSMS2">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">

                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Dear Keerthisvasav, yes it has highest priority as 999

Comment: okay, let me check n get back to you

Comment: Which Android Os version you're checking..?

Comment: @Keerthisvasan , i am checking this app in lollipop 5.1 .

Answer (score 1):

Give like that in Android Manifest File

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <receiver android:name=".IncommingSMS2" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

So, it's have the High priority, then it will work after long In Activity of Application

Comment: @Keerthisvasan this has been already implemented high priority excluding the code android:exported="true". I will add this line  and let you know thanks.

Comment: @simon Got the OP ah